# Not being able to access global array from in php

Tags: php, wordpress, global

i am having the following situation in a wordpress theme which I want to modify in a file called navigation.php

```
$array_test = array (1,2,3,4);

function func1()
{
  global $array_test;

  echo "test"; // to ensure that the function has been called
  echo $array_test[2]; // this writes nothing, though the function is being called
}
```

in the file called header.php the function `func1` is being called, still the value of `$array_test[2]` cannot be accessed,

Do you have any ideas?

EDIT:
i suspect it is an issue with wordpress or the theme, but i am not sure
the theme is the free health_care_wp_theme

Comment: It works on Ideone... http://ideone.com/dsTLY8

Comment: Likely the two files aren't included together, aren't included in the right order or the variable is being overwritten somewhere in between.

Comment: and what you get when you `dump` `$GLOBALS[2]`

Comment: $GLOBALS[2] shows nothing

Comment: @scoota269: the function is being called, as you see in the comments

Comment: @CertaiN: yes, i have tested it there before posting in stackoverflow, this is the confusing part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In navigation.php, (in case if there's no class in that file,define one)

```
class Nav
{ 
     public $array_test = array(1,2,3,4);

     public function func1()
     {  
       echo "test"; // to ensure that the function has been called
       return $this->array_test[2]; 
     }

     public function access_within_class()
     {   
       print_r($this->array_test); 
     }     
}
```

In header.php

```
include 'path/to/navigation.php';

$nav = new Nav();
$the_array = $nav->func1(); 
echo $the_array;
```

Comment: sorry, i cant pass the array to the function, it is a variable variable array, i included a simplified example (which also does not work), or have i missed something from your solution?

Comment: By right, you should be able to access the array. Did you try putting everything inside a class in navigation.php?

Comment: this will work, but i cant pass the array as an argument, i need to access it globally within the function

Comment: what should the code look like if i have a second function in the class to access the same array?

Comment: I don't understand...but basically, accessing func1 in header.php definitely doesn't need anymore arrays to be added as argument. As long as you include the main class inside any pages and initiate an object, you can always access func1.

Comment: ok, the idea is to have a global array which is accessible from any function in the navigation.php file, but i can not get it accessed at all even from a single function, i added a single function for sake of simplicity, the real code is far more complex, as the array it self is a dynamic variable, but this is another story

Comment: You want to access the array from any functions within navigation.php and at the same can be extended to other files? See my edited answer. I made the array to be public.